# catkin_make error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dump of console text:

```
$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/srikar/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/srikar/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/srikar/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/srikar/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/srikar/catkin_ws/install
Creating symlink "/home/srikar/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/srikar/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/srikar/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/srikar/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/srikar/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/srikar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/srikar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268849/catkin_make-error/) by [srikar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31582/srikar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is really not a question, but a dump of the text on the console after running `catkin_make`. We're all happy to help here, but please spend some more time on properly formulating a question next time. Please see the [wiki/Support - Guidelines for asking a question](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29).

---

As to your problem: CMake can't seem to find your C compiler. Do you have one installed? If you're using Ubuntu, make sure to install the `build-essential` package. That should sort things out.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0